# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' - Dataflow

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, psycopg2, apache-beam

I've been surfing on stackoverflow looking for a solution to this problem:

[image: Module not found error]

I've tried differents approches, unfortunately I didn't solve it.

Scenario:

I have a python script that reads from Google Pubsub, via Apache Beam, messages.
Every received message, I call a procedure that inserts into a PostgreSQL table:

[image: Postgresql table]

My method calls a PostgreSQL Stored Procedure using a psycopg2 connection:

[image]

Running my code on DirectRunner, it works fine. When I run it on Dataflow I got the message :

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'.

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you,
Juliano

Comment: That just indicates that `psycopg2` is not installed wherever you are running the code. I don't use DataFlow, so the following is generic advice: 1) If possible install `psycopg` in the environment 2) Find out what the 'native' connection library is and use it.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver , thank you for your advice. When I go to Google Cloud Plataform and "pip list" I have the **psycopg2** installed: 
psycopg2                       2.8.6
psycopg2-binary                2.8.6
That's why I'm concerned, it is installed but i can't use it. =(

Comment: Like I said I don't use DataFlow, so that is out of my depth. Best guess is that it is running in a different environment then where the `pip list` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dataflow runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/) is a temporary cluster in Google Cloud Platform.  Dataflow runner does *not* have your local libraries.  You need to specify [`--requirements_file requirements.txt`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) on the command line when you run your dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

psycopg2 is package that uses binary dependencies.
If you want to run dataflow in most secure way (isolated network) there is a chance it won't build.
Instead requirements-file param above, better download psycopg2-binary wheel

```
pip download --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --no-binary=:none: psycopg2-binary
```

and pass file name as **extra_packages** param.
This will work with classic template as well. Your build machine will put all necessaries wheels on worker, and won't try to build from source with that.